# json could not be parsed - import csv and convert to vcf

Tags: python

i have found a python script to convert csv to vcf (vcard) but it does not work how i expect it. I am new to python an programming, so i think i need your help to solve the problem.
Here is the Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
    Author : Mridul Ahuja (original author)
    Description : A small command line tool to convert CSV files to VCard files

"""

import os
import sys
import csv
import json

def print_card(target, values):
    target.write('BEGIN:VCARD' + "\n")
    target.write('VERSION:3.0' + "\n")
    target.write('N:' + values["name"] + ';' + "\n")
    target.write('FN:' + values["full"] + "\n")
    target.write('NICKNAME:' + values["nick"] + "\n")
    target.write('X-MAIDENNAME:' + values["maiden"] + "\n")
    target.write('ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;' + values["street"] + ';' + values["city"] + ';;' + values["zip"] + ';' + values["country"] + "\n")
    target.write('TEL;HOME;VOICE:' + values["tel"].replace("'", '') + "\n")
    target.write('TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:' + values["mobile"].replace("'", '') + "\n")
    target.write('EMAIL:' + values["mail"] + "\n")
    target.write('BDAY:' + values["bday"] + "\n")
    target.write('ORG:' + values["org"] + "\n")
    target.write('ROLE:' + values["role"] + "\n")
    target.write('URL:' + values["url"] + "\n")
    target.write('NOTE: ' + values["note"] + "\n")
    target.write('END:VCARD' + "\n")
    target.write("\n")


def convert_to_vcard(input_file, single_output, input_file_format, target):

    if not os.path.exists('csv2vcf'):
        os.makedirs('csv2vcf')

    FN = input_file_format['name']-1 if 'name' in input_file_format else None
    GIVEN = input_file_format['given']-1 if 'given' in input_file_format else None
    SURNAME = input_file_format['surname']-1 if 'surname' in input_file_format else None
    PREFIX = input_file_format['prefix']-1 if 'prefix' in input_file_format else None
    NICKNAME = input_file_format['nickname']-1 if 'nickname' in input_file_format else None
    MAIDEN = input_file_format['maiden']-1 if 'maiden' in input_file_format else None
    CITY = input_file_format['city']-1 if 'city' in input_file_format else None
    STREET = input_file_format['street']-1 if 'street' in input_file_format else None
    COUNTRY = input_file_format['country']-1 if 'country' in input_file_format else None
    ZIP = input_file_format['zip']-1 if 'zip' in input_file_format else None
    ORG = input_file_format['org']-1 if 'org' in input_file_format else None
    TEL = input_file_format['tel']-1 if 'tel' in input_file_format else None
    MOBILE = input_file_format['mobile']-1 if 'mobile' in input_file_format else None
    URL = input_file_format['url']-1 if 'url' in input_file_format else None
    BDAY = input_file_format['bday']-1 if 'bday' in input_file_format else None
    ROLE = input_file_format['role']-1 if 'role' in input_file_format else None
    EMAIL = input_file_format['email']-1 if 'email' in input_file_format else None
    NOTE = input_file_format['note']-1 if 'note' in input_file_format else None

    i = 0

    with open(input_file, 'r') as source_file:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(source_file.read(1024))
        source_file.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(source_file, dialect)
        if single_output:  # if single output option is selected
            vcf = open('csv2vcf/all_contacts.vcf', 'w')
        
        for row in reader:
            N_VAL = row[SURNAME] if SURNAME is not None else ''
            N_VAL = N_VAL + ";" + row[GIVEN] if GIVEN is not None else ''
            N_VAL = N_VAL + ";;" + row[PREFIX] if PREFIX is not None else ''
            values = {
                "name": N_VAL,
                "full": row[FN] if FN is not None else row[GIVEN] + " " + row[SURNAME],
                "nick": row[NICKNAME] if NICKNAME is not None else '',
                "maiden": row[MAIDEN] if MAIDEN is not None else '',
                "zip": row[ZIP] if ZIP is not None else '',
                "city": row[CITY] if CITY is not None else '',
                "street": row[STREET] if STREET is not None else '',
                "country": row[COUNTRY] if COUNTRY is not None else '',
                "org": row[ORG] if ORG is not None else '',
                "tel": row[TEL] if TEL is not None else '',
                "mobile": row[MOBILE] if MOBILE is not None else '',
                "url": row[URL] if URL is not None else '',
                "bday": row[BDAY] if BDAY is not None else '',
                "role": row[ROLE] if ROLE is not None else '',
                "mail": row[EMAIL] if EMAIL is not None else '',
                "note": row[NOTE] if NOTE is not None else ''
            }

            # for the user
            print_card(target, values)
            print ('----------------------')

            if not single_output:  # default ( multi-file output )
                vcf = open('csv2vcf/' + values["full"] + '_' + values["mail"] + ".vcf", 'w')

            print_card(vcf, values)

            if not single_output:  # default ( multi-file output )
                vcf.close()
            i += 1

    vcf.close()
    print (str(i) + " VCARDS written")
    print ('----------------------')


def main(args):
    args_len = len(args)

    if args_len < 3 or args_len > 4:
        print("Usage:")
        print(args[0] + " CSV_FILE_NAME [ -s | --single ] INPUT_FILE_FORMAT")
        sys.exit()

    if args_len == 3:
        input_file = args[1]

        try:
            input_file_format = json.loads(args[2])
        except Exception:
            print ('\033[91m'+"ERROR : json could not be parsed"+'\033[0m')
            sys.exit()

        single_output = 0
    elif args_len == 4:
        input_file = args[1]

        if args[2] == '-s' or args[2] == '--single':
            single_output = 1
        else:
            print ('\033[91m'+"ERROR : invalid argument `" + args[2] + "`"+'\033[0m')
            sys.exit()

        try:
            input_file_format = json.loads(args[3])
        except Exception:
            print ('\033[91m'+"ERROR : json could not be parsed"+'\033[0m')
            sys.exit()

    if not os.path.exists(input_file):
        print ('\033[91m'+"ERROR : file `" + input_file + "` not found"+'\033[0m')
        sys.exit()

    convert_to_vcard(input_file, single_output, input_file_format, sys.stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

I tried to use this script in that way:

```
python csv2vcf.py tel.csv -s '{"name":1, "surname":2, "org":3}'
```

and get the following message: ERROR: json could not be parsed

Structure of tel.csv is following:

```
"Vorname";"Nachname";"Firma";"Tel";"Mobil";"Land";"Kundennummer";
"Max";"Mustermann";;"+4912345678";;"Deutschland";"1234";
```

I tried without "" in csv and , instead of ; but nothing works.

Edit: I have modified the script to get better Exception and Error Message from the programm and that shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\csv2vcf\csv2vcf.py", line 156, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Scripts\csv2vcf\csv2vcf.py", line 143, in main
    input_file_format = json.loads(args[3])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I hardcoded the json.loads and then it works, but how can i use the orignal variable instead of hardcoding this?

```
 #input_file_format = json.loads(args[3])
 input_file_format = json.loads('{"given":1, "surname":2, "org":3, "tel":4, "mobile":5}')
```

args3 Printout value: {given:1, surname:2, org:3, 4, mobile:5}

This is the problem, if i use args[3] Variable there are no names enclosed in double quotes.

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the author of the script.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, the trick is to escape the quotes to preserve them inside the script. So this works fine:

```
python csv2vcf.py tel.csv -s '{\"name\":1, \"surname\":2, \"org\":3, \"tel\":4, \"mobile\":5}'
```